# how to bind property to bootstrap 5 elements in angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, angular13

Iam using angular 13, and bootstrap 5.
for static contents, bootstrap elements are working fine.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-bs-content="popoverContent">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

But I want **data-bs-content** to be dynamic. Like below code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" [data-bs-content]="popoverContent">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

But currently angular showing error and not supporting property binding to this element.

P.S: I don't want to use ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap or other frameworks.

How can I solve this ? Please help

Comment: Try to use `[attr.bs-content]`. See this: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding

Comment: tnx for ur comment... But its not working

Answer (score 0):

I have used *data-bs-theme* in angular as folow:

**[attr.data-bs-theme]="theme"**

maybe you could try with:

**[attr.data-bs-content]="popoverContent"**