# How to toggle bootstrap dark theme in angular app?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, darkmode

I want to add bootstrap dark theme to my angular application and i don't know how to add data-bs-theme="dark" in index.html using angular?
any idea??

I don't know how to change the data-bs-theme attribute using angular

Comment: 4 words in Google: "Bootstrap dark theme Angular". And first result: https://jfhr.me/angular-bootstrap-theme-switcher/

Comment: i was specific enough when i mentioned that i wonder if there's a way to change data attribute in index.html not this way

Comment: So use google, too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273809/how-to-bind-property-to-bootstrap-5-elements-in-angular
So many examples, so many ways. You only need to play around with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So... you made me curious. For this reason I have tried it. First: This function, or `Attribute` so to say, is only available in **Bootstrap 5.3.0** which still is an Alpha at this time.

#### Update:

###### Bootstrap 5.3.0 is now official available. So you can use it regular.

---

`npm install boostrap@5.3.0-Alpha1`

After this you can use the `Attribute`. But: In Angular it's not a very good way to manipulate the index.html. It's the main entry of the app and Angular is using the underlying `<app-root>` as highest level. So we don't need index. You can (and should - so tells us Bootstraps [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#navbar)) use it on any components you need, `nav` or any `div`.

In Angular, to make it switchable, bind it as attribute:

```
<div [attr.data-bs-theme]="myTheme">
  <!-- Some Stuff -->
</div>
```

**The code part**

```
...
myTheme: string = "light";

onSwitch() {
  if (this.myTheme === "light")
    this.myTheme = "dark";
  else
    this.myTheme = "light";
}
...
```

Play around with the docs to see "how to integrate it". But: wrapper like `ng-boostrap` and so on support this alpha not full at the moment.

Comment: Nicee i did it as well , thank you u :))

Comment: this.Renderer2.setAttribute(document.querySelector('html'), 'data-bs-theme', this.ToggleModeService.mode);

Comment: i managed to set the attribute in html tags in index.html this way

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But let angular do all things about this is the better way.