# Angular 17 + Bootstrap 5 .3 enable dark / light mode

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 5 `s  doc, dark mode is support by default. [Enable dark mode](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#enable-dark-mode)

I build a FE With Angular 17, and [ng-bootstrap 16.0.0](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io). How to integrate those the dark mode ?

I am new In Angular world, so, how to set the `data-bs-theme` value ?

So far, this is that I do,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import {
  NgbDropdownItem,
  NgbModule,
  NgbProgressbar,
} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    NgbModule,
    NgbProgressbar,
    NgbDropdownItem,
  ],
  template: `
    <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-4 p-5">
      <div class="card shadow border-0">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <h1>Hello, {{ title }}</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col text-end">
              <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                  id="dropdownBasic1"
                  ngbDropdownToggle
                >
                  Change theme
                </button>
                <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                  <button ngbDropdownItem>Light</button> <!-- Do an action -->
                  <button ngbDropdownItem>Dark</button> <!-- Do an action -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
}
```

in src/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="light"> =======> Change dynamically by Angular
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Frontend</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to toggle bootstrap dark theme in angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75428868/how-to-toggle-bootstrap-dark-theme-in-angular-app)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `data-bs-theme`to  html don't work for me. But you can add to body

```
<div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
  <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="changeTheme('light')">Light</button>
  <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="changeTheme('dark')">Dark</button>
</div>

  changeTheme(theme:string)
  {
    const body=document.body as HTMLElement
    body.setAttribute('data-bs-theme',theme)
  }
```

See that you should use bootstrap.min.5.3.css

You can see in action in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fxt5ki?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

NOTE: You can add in index.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Or use

```
npm install bootstrap@5.3.2
```

Add add the .css in you angular.json, in the "styles" sections that's becomes like

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/global_styles.css"],
```